# Как вызвать метод класса из dll?

Tags: c++

Добрый день! Была обычная человеческая dll-ка с одной функцией, все работало. Обернул функцию в класс, сделал на всякий случай метод static, и теперь ничего не работает, можно ли вообще вызывать метод класса из dll-ы, и как, и можно ли, чтобы она была не static, вот уже на работающие исходники:

.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
class F{
public:
    static int foo(int i){
        return i + 1;
    }
};
```

.def

```
LIBRARY "DLL"
EXPORTS
    F::foo      @1
```

Здесь пишет, что: unresolved external symbol F::foo. Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Попробуй указать __declspec(dllexport) или __declspec(dllimport) после слова class.

Comment: дописал, но он по прежнему ругается на запись в .def файле.

Comment: и это не нужно указывать, т.к. есть .def файл

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!
Я думаю можно попробовать следующий способ: вам необходимо два проекта - первый с библиотекой, второй с тестовой программой (exe). В проект библиотеки добавляем два файла: dllclass.h и dllclass.cpp, вот их реализация:

```
// dllclass.h
#ifdef MAKE_DLL
#define CLASS_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CLASS_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class F{
public:
   static int foo(int i);
};

// dllclass.cpp
int F::foo(int i)
{
   return i + 1;
}
```

Далее необходимо в опциях компилятора добавить предъобявленную директиву препроцесоора (predefined defines): **MAKE_DLL**

Магия в том, что когда вы будете компилировать проект с библиотекой, то класс будет объявлен как *экспортируемый*, во всех остальных случаях от будет *импортируемым* (см. директивы препроцессора в dllclass.h).

Теперь надо написать программу тестирования библиотеки. В проекте с приложением создаем файл main.cpp и пишем там примерно следующее:

```
// main.cpp
#include <dllclass.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << F::foo(3) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Важно:** перед компиляцией необходимо задать в опциях пути к заголовочным файлам вашей библиотеки и файлу *.lib!

Попробуйте, должно помочь!